# Some qns regarding indexing of Apache Solr

Tags: solr, drupal-7, centos5

I have installed Solr 3.6.2 and drupal 7 on xampp for linux on my server. i have also installed solr integration module apachesolr-7.x-1.1.zip

1) when i index a file say book.csv where is this file getting stored in solr.( path_to folder name ??)

2) To know the total files indexed as well as the file names that got indexed ?

3) I am unable to understand the query syntax for solr ? what is q ,wt , what are the various parsers and implications of each ?

4) How do i find the path to the file which got indexed ? Suppose i have a file that i indexed and when i do a query search it should return the path name of the file from where it got indexed so that i could open the file for users to view it.

Comment: If you have specific questions about things that you find here in the documentation, please ask them. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/

Comment: I have one more qn and that is if i indexed a file say test.docx and i have some comments abt the file like App version=5.6.2 and Customer=ABC tech etc. what should be my curl stmt be like curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=3&literal.comment='APP VER=ABC 5.2.2,Customer=Microsoft,Date=24 Mar 2013'&commit=true" -F "myfile=@test.docx." Is my curl stmt correct ?

Comment: And i have field named comment in my schema.xml <field name="comments" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) 4) The uploaded file is split into its documents; and documents are **taken apart** and put into an index. Its similar an index volume of the world book: 'relativity' might point to 'M' volume for 'modern physics' and 'E' volume for 'Einstein'. Or a book that classifies taxpayers by tax brackets.

This behavior is controlled by `stored` and `indexed` properties in schema.

The data goes into `data` directory of solr (next to `conf`). You can backup this directory by copying it.

2) http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters and http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters . Particularly use `fl`

3) Please try solr for yourself. You can get it up and try queries in no time.

Comment: Your answer was pretty good except for the fact that when i have indexed a pdf file, imagine like a companny's annual newsletter. when i indexed it the field text had stored=false. so will i have to re-index my file after i have fixed the schema.xml file with that field to be true??? I am trying real hard to get the contents of the pdf displayed part of the response but all i get is the metadata of the pdf.

Comment: You have to reindex. And Tika will reduce the PDF to its text.

Comment: I havent tried your above step but just to let you knw that wehn i clicked statistics link in my admin page for solr i.e http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ for the update/extract query handler the value of  stats:  is  note : not initialized yet . what does this mean ? coz i used this query handler to index my pdf file.

Comment: Also when i indexed my books.csv file from example docs and i used the update/csv query handler and its stats : is also note : not initialized yet but this had retrieved all the contents of the books.csv file. so i guess your above suggestion should be correct ? let me try that